# Apache Camel HTTPS4 component producing plain HTTP request

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https, apache-camel

I am trying to configure the https4 component inside a route builder class using the following code snippet:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
    ksp.setResource("C:/dev/cascerts/my.jks");
    ksp.setPassword("mypass");

    TrustManagersParameters tmp = new TrustManagersParameters();
    tmp.setKeyStore(ksp);

    SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
    scp.setTrustManagers(tmp);

    HttpComponent httpComponent = getContext().getComponent("https4", HttpComponent.class);
    httpComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);

    from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=10s")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethods.GET))
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, constant("page=" + this.page))
        .to("https4://hostname:8444/resourceuri?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
        .process(this.new InventoryResponseProcessor());
}
```

However the server responds with *400: The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port*.
It seems as if the https4 component is producing plain http requests. What am I doing wrong?

Camel version: 2.13.2, application runs on apache tomcat 8.0.14

Thank you in advance

Comment: The setting looks good. Can you try to run the camel route without deploying into tomcat?

Comment: I think that the actual problem is that the underlying Http Client interprets https requests as plain http ones, unless the default https port 443 is used in the URI. For the case above, a new https scheme using port 8444 must be registered in the Http Client. I'll try it and let you know.